# function that accepts multiple trait object types as arguments

Tags: rust

`ff` accepts an `A` trait object and `gg` accepts a `B` trait object.
What would be the best way to write a function that accepts a trait object from A or B?

```
trait A {}
trait B {}

fn ff(arg: &dyn A) {}

fn gg(arg: &dyn B) {}
```

I want something like:

```
fn jj(arg: (&dyn A || &dyn B)) {}
```

Comment: You didn't provide a very useful example. Do `A` and `B` share some behavior that `fn jj` wants to use? If so, you could move that behavior into a separate trait.

Comment: yes, they share some behaviour. I thought of making a new trait and making it supertrait of A and B. But I don't know if this is the best way of doing it...

Comment: Using a single trait interface would probably be better than the alternative: an enum